# How to produce a column of weighted data based off of three years values

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

| Year_Code | Area_Code | Area_ItemName_ENG | OO_EST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201112 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2000 |
| 201213 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2500 |
| 201314 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2200 |
| 201415 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2400 |
| 201516 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2250 |
| 201617 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2300 |
| 201718 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2700 |
| 201819 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2550 |
| 201920 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2100 |
| 202021 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2350 |

I need to produce a new column where the values in OO_EST are weighted based on the parameters in the Year_Code column.

For 201112, I need: 0.75 x OO_EST of current year (201112) + 0.25 x OO_EST of following year (201212).

I.e. 0.75 x 2000 + 0.25 x 2500 = 2125

For 201112 < Year_Code < max(Year_Code), I need: 0.25 x OO_EST of previous year + 0.5 x OO_EST of current year + 0.25 x OO_EST of following year.

E.g. For 201213 <- 0.25 x 2000 + 0.5 x 2500 + 0.25 x 2200 = 2300

Finally, for the max(Year_Code), I need: 0.75 x current year + 0.25 x previous year.

The new data frame would look as follows:

| Year_Code | Area_Code | Area_ItemName_ENG | OO_EST | smoothingOO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201112 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2000 | 2125 |
| 201213 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2500 | 2300 |
| 201314 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2200 | 2325 |
| 201415 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2400 | 2312.5 |
| 201516 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2250 | 2300 |
| 201617 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2300 | 2387.5 |
| 201718 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2700 | 2562.5 |
| 201819 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2550 | 2475 |
| 201920 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2100 | 2275 |
| 202021 | 512 | Isle of Anglesey | 2350 | 2287.5 |

This needs to be done for a further 234 rows with different Area_Code's.

When new data is imported, I need the code to be able to follow the same calculations with a new max(Year_Code) value and the previous latest year smoothed with the new OO_EST values.

I hope that explanation makes sense. I have tried loads of different methods but to no prevail. I can't seem to find anything online that is similar to this issue so apologies if the answer is already available.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! I am very new to rStudio and this was my first question ever asked so apologies if I formatted the question wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force: in base R, we can use `ave()` to run the computation on grouped data.

**Code**

```
data$smoothingOO <- 
  ave(x = data$OO_EST,
    data$Area_Code, # grouping 
    FUN = \(x) {
      # first row 
      y1 <- x[1L] * .75 + x[2L] * .25 
      # last row
      yl <- x[length(x)] * .75 + x[length(x) - 1L] * .25 
      # "inner rows" 
      y <- x * .5 + .25 * c(0L, x[-length(x)]) + .25 * c(x[-1L], 0)
      # combine first, inner minus first and last, and last row
      c(y1, y[-c(1L, length(y))], yl)
      })
```

gives

```
> data$smoothingOO
 [1] 2125.0 2300.0 2325.0 2312.5 2300.0 2387.5 2562.5 2475.0 2275.0 2287.5 2125.0 2300.0 2325.0 2312.5 2287.5
```

**Modified test data**

I added the first five rows of the provided data to the end of this data. For those rows, I changed `Area_Code` to 333.

```
data <- 
  structure(list(
    Year_Code = c(201112, 201213, 201314, 201415, 201516, 
                  201617, 201718, 201819, 201920, 202021, 
                  201112, 201213, 201314, 201415, 201516), 
    Area_Code = c(512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 
                  512, 512, 333, 333, 333, 333, 333), 
    Area_ItemName_ENG = c(" Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  ", " Isle of Anglesey  ", 
                          " Isle of Anglesey  "), 
    OO_EST = c(2000, 2500, 2200, 2400, 2250, 2300, 2700, 2550, 
               2100, 2350, 2000, 2500, 2200, 2400, 2250)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think editing a question (Q) after a week is no good practice. Please ask a new Q instead. Make it clear, brief, and reproducible.